# For-EachObject loop iterative variable issue

Tags: powershell

This is driving me nuts.

I want to create a script that for all users who's name start with "John", creates a text file with the users username and name.

Here is the script:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like "John*"} -Property Name, SamAccountName |
ForEach-Object {
  Get-ADUser -Filter {name -eq $_.Name} |
  Select-Object -Property Name, SamAccountName |
  Out-File "c:\PS\$_.Name.txt"
}
```

This works but the out-file(s) name isn't the users name, but rather it is its ADsPath; `CN=John Doe,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=local.Name.txt`

For some reason the `$_.Name` doesn't resolve correctly in the out-file CMD-let. `$_` refrences the object properly but the `.Name` is interpreted as just a string

`WriteHost $_.Name` works so why doesn't `Out-File "C:\PS\$_.Name.txt"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"$_.Name"` doesn't work because you're inside a string -- PowerShell expands only the variable, not your intended expression. For that, you want `"$($_.Name)"`. Everything within `$()` is evaluated as a single expression. See [about_Quoting_Rules](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847740) for more details.

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted, just didn't know how to do it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Only variables get expanded in string, not properties. To make this work you need to use the `$()` syntax:

```
Out-File "c:\PS\$($_.Name).txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
Out-File ("c:\PS\" + $_.Name + ".txt")
```

How should powershell know where does you variable stop and your text start? It's not that smart. It's looking for `$` symbol and considers the word after it to be a variable. All the rest is text. You can use it with variables, but here you want to use it with property of a variable.

Comment: Tried this, getting `Out-File : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Encoding'. The argument "+" does not belong to the set "unknown,string,unicode,bigendianunicode,utf8,utf7,utf32,ascii,default,oem" specified by the ValidateSet attribute.`

Comment: You need to do `("c:\PS\" + $_.Name + ".txt")`